# Fire Action After async pipe has subscribed to an Observable

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, angular-pipe

I have the following component:

```js
data$: Observable < MyApolloQueryResult > ;

constructor(private myService: MyService) {}

ngOnInit() {
  this.data$ = this.myService.getData();
}
```

```html
<div *ngIf="data$ | async as data; else loading">
  ...
</div>
```

As you can see I only subscribe to the `Observable` within the component template. The question is, how do I fire an action (like set a variable within `myService` above) only *after* the `async` pipe above has subscribed to the `Observable`, in other words, after having made sure this `Observable` is no longer cold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to have side-effects, use the [`do` operator](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-do).

```
this.data$ = this.myService.getData().do(value => {
  // side effect
})
```

The function passed to `do` operator will be called each time the observable emits, for each subscription -- so be careful to subscribe only once, or he effect will happen multiple times.

---

However, this usually means that you're not using the power of RxJS completely. Instead of doing a side-effect, try using [some of the operators](http://rxmarbles.com/) to manipulate the stream the way you'd like.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand. `getData()` *does* return an `Observable`! I thought that was clear from the above?

Comment: In that case, I don't understand what's wrong with your code. It should work: the request will be fired once the template is created. What is exactly happening in your case?

Comment: My question says that I want to fire an action after the `async` pipe subscribes to my `Observable`; for example, set a variable to `false`.

Comment: Ah, you want to fire some _other_ action. Sorry for the misunderstanding! Updating the answer in a minute.

Comment: Thank you, all I'm trying to do is to make sure this `Observable` has been subscribed to once, and so that the data has been loaded. This allows me to later do some `map`ping on this data and return it. I'm therefore planning to simply set a boolean variable within `myService` above to `true`. Would you have done it differently?

Comment: I'd have a variable in the service become an observable, too. Then you can express the change from `false` to `true` using a `.map` or something similar. Really depends on the whole context.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm still thinking about your last comment. May you demonstrate it please?

Comment: For example, have `var$` instead of `var` and then just do `var$ = this.data$.map(data => /* str based on data that returns true or false */)`. Then you don't need side-effects because that happens when observable emits, instead you just transform the emitted value into a new observable.

Comment: That's great! Since this event fires only once, can I use `take(1)` instead of `map` in your comment above?

Comment: You can use both.